# Oracle 10G Installation on Windows

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle10g, failed-installation

I have a database: Oracle SQL Developer 3.2.20.9
an asp.net web application running locally on a pc with Windows 7 enterprise 64 bit, and to developed it I used Visual Studio 2013.
Now I should connect the application with the db so I' m trying to install:

Oracle 10g ODAC and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio .NET

I get this Error:
*"Abnormal program termination. an internal error has occured. Please provide the following files to Oracle Support:
Unknown
Unknown
Unknown"*

Could I connect the webapp in other ways?
When I go to Server Explorer in Visual Studio and I choose connect to database -> add connection -> Oracle database -> .NET framework Data Provider for Oracle
I get:
*"This provider is deprecated and should not be used. Instead, download Oracle Developer Tools for visual Studio for comprehensive integration with Oracle databases."*

Comment: You are using Oracle 10 ODAC which is not supported for Windows 7. The most recent personal Windows OS that is supported is Vista. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/install10202-083849.html

Comment: Thanks for you' re answer. What should I do? they asked me to connect this webapp to the db and displays the result of some queries: but I can't find the way to connect this  with the database.

Comment: I just have a computer with Windows 7 enterprise 64 bit, an application developed with Visual Studio 2013, and Oracle SQL Developer 3.2.20.9. That's all I have.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports connections back two versions.  You should try installing the ODAC client for 11g as that will connect to a version 10 database and supports windows 7.
Seeing as SQL developer is free why not get the latest version 4.02 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)

Be sure to get an ODAC version that matches the bitness of the database, 32 bit or 64 bit.  You can check this by logging onto the machine with Run > cmd > sqlplus > connect as your user/your password.  If the header that is returned does not say 64 bit then the database is a 32 bit install and you need ODAC to match that.

And seeing as connecting to Oracle is popular question a good troubleshooting routine is

- connect from sqlplus on the database
- connect with sql developer from your client pc
- then try connecting through Visual Studio.